# Enable / Disable Menuitem

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a RCP App with target-platform 3.7.
I like to enable a menuItem only if a specific view is active otherwise it should be disabled.
I try it via expression like shown in the plugin.xml below, but the menuItem is always active.

```xml
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="pgui.handler.SaveHandler"
            id="pgui.rcp.command.save"
            name="Save">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
     <view
          allowMultiple="true"
          class="pgui.view.LogView"
          id="pgui.view.LogView"
          name="logview"
          restorable="true">
     </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="fileMenu"
               label="File">
            <command
                  commandId="pgui.rcp.command.save"
                  label="Save"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Save the active log file.">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
    </extension>
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="pgui.rcp.command.save">
         <activeWhen>
            <with
                  variable="activePart">
               <instanceof
                     value="pgui.view.LogView">
               </instanceof>
            </with>
         </activeWhen>
      </handler>
   </extension>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove the **defaultHandler** from your command.

Next, add your handler class to your **handler** extension point instead.

Basically, the mechanism allows you to define multiple handlers for the same command, using different **activeWhen** expressions to have the command handled by different handler classes in different circumstances.

If all of the **activeWhen** expressions on all of the defined handlers for a command evaluate to false, *and there is a **defaultHandler** defined for the command itself*, then that default handler will be used for the command.  The command will, essentially, always be active, since there's always a default handler around to handle it.

For example, if you had both your existing LogView, and another view full of unicorns, and you wanted to use the same **pgui.rcp.command.save** command to handle the saving of items from either view:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command
        id="pgui.rcp.command.save"
        name="Save">
    </command>
</extension>
:
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
        class="pgui.handler.SaveLogHandler"
        commandId="pgui.rcp.command.save">

        <activeWhen>
            <with variable="activePart">
                <instanceof value="pgui.view.LogView">
                </instanceof>
            </with>
        </activeWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
:
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
        class="pgui.handler.SaveUnicornHandler"
        commandId="pgui.rcp.command.save">

        <activeWhen>
            <with variable="activePart">
                <instanceof value="pgui.view.UnicornView">
                </instanceof>
            </with>
        </activeWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the defaultHandler was the mistake. I removed it and added it as class-tag to the handler extension.